# How to destruct Object Data On certain time

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have one singleton object which actually store user activity. I wanted to remove this data on certain time ( at every night 12 ). I wanted to know How we can achieve this with out having different thread running.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to the singleton that returns the last date it ran:

```
static Date lastRun = new Date(); //when the class initializes

Date lastDateRan() {
    return lastRun;
}
```

Then add another method that checks if today > lastRun (pay attention to check only the date - not time/hour - in case you decide to use TimeStamp or any other library).

Whenever the object is called, check:

```
if (today > lastRun) {
    lastRun = today;
    // and clean the object.
}
```

It won't run every-day exactly at midnight, but it'll have the exact same effect! (the first call after midnight will get "fresh" data)

Comment: side note: as is it's not thread-safe. It wasn't explicitly required in the question but since we're talking about a singleton that's something to keep in mind

Comment: @Yuri you can say that about (almost) any answer here in SO :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code :

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              Object_name.close   //your code to cleanup object
        }
    }, 
    12*60*60*1000  /*time after which it will run again*/ 
 );
```